# JSTL <c:if> tag - Checking whether Java Bean method returns True

Tags: java, if-statement, jstl, javabeans

I currently have a `.jsp` file as follows (partly shown):

```
<jsp:useBean id="cart" class="edu.unsw.comp9321.assignment1.CartBean"
scope="session" />  
<tr>
    <td><input type="submit" name="cartBtn" value="Go To Checkout"/></td>
    <td><input type="submit" name="cartBtn" value="Remove From Cart"/></td>
    <c:if test="${cart.isCartListEmpty eq true}"> 
        <td><input type="submit" name="cartBtn" value="Back To Search"/></td>
    </c:if> 
</tr>
```

The bean `cart` has the code:

```
public boolean isCartListEmpty(){
    if (this.cart.isEmpty())
        return true;
    return false;
}
```

The problem is I am getting an error with the following line:

```
<c:if test="${cart.isCartListEmpty eq true}">
```

Could someone please tell me the correct way to evaluate whether the bean method is returning `true` or `false`?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Could you try with `test="${cart.cartListEmpty}"`?

Comment: Also, `if condition then return true else return false` should be simplified by `return condition`.

Comment: @sp00m Thank you. This seems to have resolved the issue!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The EL `${bean.attribute}` will try to call the method `getAttribute()` or `isAttribute()` of the `bean`.

So in your case, `${cart.isCartListEmpty}` will look for a method `getIsCartListEmpty()` or `isIsCartListEmpty()` in your `cart`.

What you need is thus `${cart.cartListEmpty}` to call the appripriate `isCartListEmpty()` method.

---

Side notes:

1. No need to add the `eq true` part since `isCartListEmpty()` already returns a boolean.
2. You can (should?) simplify your `isCartListEmpty()` method body to `return this.cart.isEmpty()`.